# Using unix date in OS X (10.6) bash is causing "illegal time format" error

Tags: macos, bash, unix, date

I'm unable to use date (under OS X 10.6, using bash) without getting the following "illegal time format" error:

```
$ date "+DATE: %Y-%m-%d%nTIME: %H:%M:%S"
DATE: 2012-03-29
TIME: 11:39:30
date: illegal time format
usage: date [-jnu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]
```

I'm taking that example direct from the man page. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Anything in `alias | grep -i date`?

Comment: What about locale? Does it work with `LC_ALL=C date +...`?

Comment: Gnnn. I've discovered the problem. I'll post an answer when SO lets me. Basically: Problem Exists Between Chair And Keyboard - or, to be more precise - problem exists in .bash_profile. Of course the clue is right there in the output - it's correctly outputting the date *and* the error message. Le sigh.

Comment: Indeed!  .. I was about to ask why it printed correct output _and_ then carped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So - this is an illustration of stupidity. Not interested in how stupidity ends up on Stack Overflow? Stop reading.

I was trying to add time to my prompt. Rather than relying on \t, I wanted to use date (I have a prompt file that is used across shells). Full of confidence (and who wouldn't be - it's just date, right? It's not like I'm trying to configure sendmail or anything), I added this to my PS1:

```
date "%H:%M" # << the 1st stupid thing I did
```

… then switched to my prompt. At this point I suddenly thought "I'm sure there's a shorthand for %H:%M", and called up the manpage.

Then I reloaded my profile (not noticing the error I got - the 2nd stupid thing I did) and typed

```
date "+%R"
```

… and obviously got both the output of date, and the error. Cue half an hour of me mashing my face into the desk and asking SO for help while the answer was right in front of me - the output of date *and* the error. I'd managed in the space of about 20 seconds to completely forget I'd added anything to my .bash_profile.

Beggars belief.

My lessons from this:

1. Don't get distracted
2. Follow a sequence
3. Quit fiddling with your damned PS1 and do some real work for a change

Answer (score 2):

Works OK for me in OS X 10.6.8:

```
$ date "+DATE: %Y-%m-%d%nTIME: %H:%M:%S"
DATE: 2012-03-29
TIME: 11:46:52
$
```

Are you using something other than the standard `date` that ships with OS X ?

```
$ which date
/bin/date
$
```

Comment: Nope, I'm using the same as you :/

Comment: The version of bash shouldn't matter; it's the version of `date` that's relevant.  MacOS uses the BSD `date` command by default; here's the [man page](http://www.unix.com/man-page/OSX/1/DATE/), which refers to [strftime(3)](http://www.unix.com/man-page/OSX/3/strftime/).  It should work.  The OP says in a comment he's found the problem; I'm not sure what it could be.

Comment: @Keith: good point - for some reason I thought that `date` was a bash built-in - my mistake - answer updated.